# Visual Studio 2012 not showing all compiler errors

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2012.

I have recently changed a function signature in our Web Application by removing a parameter from the signature.

This function is called from most of the aspx pages on our site.

I am trying to refactor all the function calls to also remove the paramater from the call, however, when I rebuild the solution from Visual Studio the Error List only contains errors from one or two pages.

If I fix these errors and recompile a couple more errors show from different pages.

I would have thought that a recompile should show all compiler errors found during compilation and not just a couple of errors every time I recompile.

Is there a limit to the number of pages Visual Studio tries to compile if previous pages have errors?

Is there any way of removing this limit?

It takes a while to recompile the site each time, and it would be much faster for me to have a full list of errors rather than the bits and pieces I get on each recompile.

Comment: If your web solution is broken up into many projects and you have VSCommands installed, the latter can (if configured) trigger VS to stop on first error rather than continuing to build the rest of the solution

Comment: Solution only contains a single project in this case.